# Is $\lim_{x \to -a^{-}}{f(x)}$ the same as $\lim_{x \to (-a)^{+}}{f(x)}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, notation

Is the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ appraches $-a$ from the left.
$$\lim_{x \to (-a)^{-}}{f(x)}$$
the same as
$$\lim_{x \to -a^{-}}{f(x)}$$
where $a>0$, or does removing the parentheses change the meaning?

I reasoned that they are not the same because in the second case, we can multiply $x$ and $-a^{-}$ by $-1$:
$$\lim_{-x \to a^{-}}{f(x)}$$
If we substitute in the precise definition of limits this means,
$$a-\delta<-x<a\overset{\times -1}{\implies} -a+\delta>x>-a\overset{rearrange}{\implies} (-a)<x<(-a)+\delta$$
which is equivalent to
$$\lim_{x \to (-a)^{+}}{f(x)}$$
so
$$\lim_{x \to -a^{-}}{f(x)}=\lim_{x \to (-a)^{+}}{f(x)}$$

Comment: The notation for limit is always $\lim_{\text{variable } \to \text{ value}} $ and the variable here can not be an expression like $-x$. If you want to introduce $-x$ better put a variable $t=-x$ and then $$\lim_{x\to - a^{-}} f(x) =\lim_{t\to a^{+}} f(-t) $$

Comment: I don't see why the variable can't be an expression.

Comment: Because it is not defined that way.

Comment: BTW your fault lies in multiplying by $-1$. It should lead to $-x\to a^{+} $ even if we allow expression in place of variable. This is what I have written using $t=-x$.

Comment: Thanks alot!, Paramanand Singh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to  Paramanand Singh's comment, I know what's the fault. Here's is his comment.

"your fault lies in multiplying by $-1$. It should lead to $-x\to a^-$ even if we allow expression in place of variable."

Answer (score 1):

Is the $\lim _{x\to -a^-} f(x)$ the same as $\lim _{x\to (-a)^-} f(x)$?

Yes this is true Both are the limit as $x$ approaches $-a$ from the left.

Comment: $x$ approaches $-a$ from left and not $a$ from left.

Comment: Yep! fixed it thanks

Comment: But if that's the case then where did I go wrong in showing that
$$\lim_{x \to -a^{-}}{f(x)}=\lim_{x \to (-a)^{+}}{f(x)}$$

Comment: Where you went wrong was by assuming $\lim_{x \to -a^-}f(x)=\lim_{-x\to a^-} f(x)$.   It's not, and you clearly were able to show that. The odd part is that your even doing this in the first place. Usually if we have a point where $x$ approaches a negative value we set $a$ to be that value. Example: $\lim_{x\to -1^-} 1/x$. This is the right hand limit as $x\to a^-$ where $a=-1$ we can't really say $-x \to a^-$ as this inverts the entire relationship. As you showed. I hope this clears up the issue.